# Exchange 2010 hidden folder still visible for users

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I have setup an Exchange search folder in users mailboxes under the 'Top of Information Store', and set the PR_ATTR_HIDDEN tag to TRUE.

This works for most of my Exchange 2010 environments. But, for some reason, on some servers (different environments) these folders will remain visible in Outlook for many users (not all).

Question here: what causes the hidden folders to be visible, even with the PR_ATTR_HIDDEN tag set to true.

Please advice :)

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the folder in the root, rather than under "Top of Information Store" if you want to be sure the user never sees it. Using the PR_ATTR_HIDDEN property relies on the client to honor it, so it isn't fool-proof.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I discussed that same point of view with the developers of the application. However, Microsoft confirmed to them that the location is good. But than, other applications like Enterprise Vault and BlackBerry have issues.